# How do injection with JPA?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0

Is possible do injection in EntityManager with EclipseLink 2.3 ?

This is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SuaParte" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
                // classes..
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm new with JPA so I created this persistence.xml file at first just to test to see if it works, but now I would like to use `@PersistenceContext` to don't have to worry about manage the `EntityMangerFactory` and `EntityManager`.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo Java EE Web Developers with GlassFish v3.

**UPDATE:**
I follow @Andrei Bodnarescu approach and this [tutorial](http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/08/06/creating-and-configuring-a-mysql-datasource-in-glassfish-application-server/) too and everything is fine to get a connection with my database through GF3:

[image: Ping database]

And i change my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SuaParte" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/mysql</jta-data-source>
                //classes.. 
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

So i try to persist something in my database:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class DaoUser {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="SuaParte")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void persist(User user){
        try{
            em.persist(user);
            }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And it returns a `java.lang.NullPointerException` in `em.persist(user);`.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What's the problem you're having when using `@PersistenceContext`? That's not entirely clear from your question. It should work just fine in Glassfish if you change transaction type to `JTA`.

Comment: @BalusC, i didn't have created a connection pool in GlassFish, I didn't know I have to do that.
I already do what Andrei told, but now returns a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: It's most likely that you're missing  some dependencies necessary for CDI to work. It's hard to tell without more details. If you wan't a working example of JPA2 + EJB3 + CDI in glassfish, checkout my little project at http://myprojects2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/other_projects/jpa2Exam/

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the transaction-type to JTA as follows -

```
<persistence-unit name="SuaParte" transaction-type="JTA">
```

And then you can use `@PersistenceContext` as follows if you want `Glassfish` to `inject` the `EntityManager` into your `EJB` -

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyEjb {

    @PersistenceContext("SuaParte")
    private EntityManager suaParteEM; 

}
```

You can do in `Servlet` and `ManagedBean` too.

Also, on your `Glassfish` server you can create `JDBC Connection Pool` and `JDBC Resource`, give it a `JNDI name` and use it to declare your `EntityManager` in the `persistence.xml` as follows -

```
<persistence-unit name="SuaParte" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>JNDI_Name_Of_JDBC_Resource</jta-data-source>
```

You can create the `JDBC Resources` on from the `Glassfish Admin-Console`.

Comment: could you please help me solve my problem ?
I do as you and Andrei Bodnarescu said, but still gives java.lang.NullPointerException exception, and I really don't know why this is happening, I spent 2 days on this and nothing so far, could you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

BheshG's answer is very good, here's just some small addendums.

- i think that in order to activate CDI and thus have dependency injection you need to create an empty beans.xml file that you must place in the WEB-INF folder of your project
- To create a data source in GF3 and expose it via JNDI like BheshG sais, you must to basically this:

  1. resources->JDBC->JDBC Connection pools and make a connection pool
  2. Create a datasource that will use the pool.

(I wanted to post images with examples for conenction pool and datasource, but I can't since I don't have reputation points. In order to not seem spammy and trolly, I'm just gonna say: email me if you want more details or an example project, as I'm working on a tutorial on exactly that right now)

Now you can use that datasource in the persistence.xml file to attach it to a persistence unit:

```
    <persistence-unit name="emJTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/postgre_ds_jta</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/emp-mappings.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>model.Employee</class>
    <class>model.ProjectManager</class>
    <class>model.Department</class>
    <class>model.Project</class>
    <class>model.Phone</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>       
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: i update my post, could you please take a look in my new situation ?
Thanks dude.

Comment: Andrei, please dude, help me, i don't know your email, didn't found in your profile, i really need some help here..